# How to download SFTP file by using regular expression in JSch

Tags: java, regex, sftp, jsch

I have lots of file on server named like:

```
STMTPULL.160618_030020 
O48PRMBATCH_170618_070209 
O48PRMBATCH_160618_030106
STMTPOST.160618_030020
```

I want to use regex to locate the newest `O48PRMBATCH*`

Now I only can download file with an actual file name. This is not enough now.

How can I change my code to implement this feature? Thank you.

Here is my code (Code has been updated, it works fine):

```
public class DownloadFile {

    public SFTPChannel getSFTPChannel() {
        return new SFTPChannel();
    }

    public void downloadFile(String srcPath, String dstPath, String fileName) throws Exception {

        DownloadFile test = new DownloadFile();

        Map<String, String> sftpDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // Set host, port, user name, password
        sftpDetails.put(SFTPConstants.SFTP_REQ_HOST, "172.16.1.180");
        sftpDetails.put(SFTPConstants.SFTP_REQ_USERNAME, "v01uc");
        sftpDetails.put(SFTPConstants.SFTP_REQ_PASSWORD, "v01uc");
        sftpDetails.put(SFTPConstants.SFTP_REQ_PORT, "22");

        SFTPChannel channel = test.getSFTPChannel();
        ChannelSftp chSftp = channel.getChannel(sftpDetails, 60000);

        String src = srcPath + fileName;

        Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> obj = chSftp.ls(src);
        ArrayList<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> iList = new ArrayList<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++){
            iList.add(obj.get(i));
        }

        Collections.sort(iList);

        int index = obj.size() - 1;
        String sFile = srcPath + iList.get(index).getFilename();
        String dst = dstPath + iList.get(index).getFilename();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        try {
            chSftp.get(sFile, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            chSftp.quit();
            channel.closeChannel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function to download files matching a regular expression in JSch.

You have to code it yourself.

- use the `ChannelSftp.ls` to retrieve a list of the files;
- iterate the list, looking for files matching the regular expression;
- download the matching files, one by one.